# Make first name mandatory using validation rule

Tags: apex, page-layout, validation-rule

I had this requirement where I had to make first name mandatory. I used validation rule to do so because you can't make just first name mandatory from the page layout.

Now from the user perspective there is no red line beside the first name field (**to show that it is required**). As per my knowledge, it is not possible since it is made mandatory from validation rule. But I still need confirmation.

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspect, you can't show the red marker (at least, not without Visualforce). Given that limitation, you'll just have to hope users are eventually trained to do so by virtue of this rule stopping them until they get it right.